# getting a different path when using Chrome or Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is my code:

```
  public ActionResult PostFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, int NoteId)  
        {    
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
            string fullname = f.FullName; //fullname changes depending on if I am using IE or Chrome
        }
```

This is my View(`PostFile.cshtml`):

```
@model RiPSShared.Models.RiPSModels.AgencyNote
<form action="@Url.Action("PostFile", "AgencyNotes", new { NoteId=Model.aut_id})" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file1"> File name:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />    
</form>
```

Why am I getting a different path for the file parameter? When I'm using IE is the correct path`("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\sds - Copy (5).docx")` but when using Chrome I get the wrong path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\`
I'm using the variable fullname to get the path value...

Comment: what is `file.FileName` giving you ? Is it not the full name ?

Comment: @Shyju `file.FileName` is giving me just the name of the file not the complete path to it, I would like to get the real path using Chrome too, something like `fullname =  "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\sds - Copy (5).docx"` and not `fullname = C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\`

Comment: Just curious, Why you need the path in client machine in the server ?

Comment: I'm trying to upload files from any location into blob Azure following this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#upload-a-blob-into-a-container  and I'm stuck trying to set the local path file in here: `using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))`

Comment: @Shyju Maybe would be better if I create another question about this topic

Comment: why do you even need to do that ? you can use `HttpPostedFileBase` to get the stream

Comment: @Shyju I've created a new question for this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364856/upload-file-into-blob-azure I'm new with blob azure and `HttpPostedFileBase` if you know how to do this I'll appreciate yor answer there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE apparently posts the entire original path, which is a **security disclosure issue**. Fortunately Chrome doesn't, so you only receive the plain file name, which is then augmented by your calls to `new FileInfo(file.FileName).FullName` in the running context of your IISExpress process.

Comment: how using Chrome shoud I get the same result than using IE? for example I would like to get using Chrome `fullname = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\sds - Copy (5).docx"` and not fullname = `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\`  ??

Comment: You'll have to accept that the filename is "sds - Copy (5).docx" and forget about the path. The path should not be there, IE behaviour is questionable if not plain wrong. Better just strip off the path if you receive one.